# Wait for all Firebase data query requests before executing code

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to fetch data from different collections in my cloud Firestore database in advance before I process them and apply them to batch, I created two async functions, one to capture the data and another to execute certain code only after all data is collected, I didn't want the code executing and creating errors before the data is fetched when i try to access the matchesObject after the async function to collect data is finished, it keeps saying "it cannot access a property matchStatus of undefined", i thought took care of that with async and await? could anyone shed some light as to why it is undefined one moment

```
axios.request(options).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Total matches count :' + response.data.matches.length);

  const data = response.data;
  var matchesSnapshot;
  var marketsSnapshot;
  var tradesSnapshot;
  var betsSnapshot;

  matchesObject = {};
  marketsObject = {};
  tradesObject = {};
  betsObject = {};

  start();

  async function checkDatabase() {
    matchesSnapshot = await db.collection('matches').get();
    matchesSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      matchesObject[doc.id] = doc.data();
      console.log('matches object: ' + doc.id.toString())
    });

    marketsSnapshot = await db.collection('markets').get();
    marketsSnapshot.forEach(doc2 => {
      marketsObject[doc2.id] = doc2.data();
      console.log('markets object: ' + doc2.id.toString())
    });

    tradesSnapshot = await db.collection('trades').get();
    tradesSnapshot.forEach(doc3 => {
      tradesObject[doc3.id] = doc3.data();
      console.log('trades object: ' + doc3.id.toString())
    });

    betsSnapshot = await db.collection('bets').get();
    betsSnapshot.forEach(doc4 => {
      betsObject[doc4.id] = doc4.data();
      console.log('bets object: ' + doc4.id.toString())
    });
  }


  async function start() {
    await checkDatabase();
    // this is the part which is undefined, it keeps saying it cant access property matchStatus of undefined
    console.log('here is matches object  ' + matchesObject['302283']['matchStatus']);

    if (Object.keys(matchesObject).length != 0) {
      for (let bets of Object.keys(betsObject)) {

        if (matchesObject[betsObject[bets]['tradeMatchId']]['matchStatus'] == 'IN_PLAY' && betsObject[bets]['matched'] == false) {
          var sfRef = db.collection('users').doc(betsObject[bets]['user']);
          batch11.set(sfRef, {
            accountBalance: admin.firestore.FieldValue + parseFloat(betsObject[bets]['stake']),
          }, {
            merge: true
          });

          var sfRef = db.collection('bets').doc(bets);
          batch12.set(sfRef, {
            tradeCancelled: true,
          }, {
            merge: true
          });
        }
      }
     
     }

    });
```

Comment: That error message would imply that `/matches/302283` is not in your database.

Comment: i checked and its there, what could be the problem? one moment its undefined and the net moment it finds the value

Answer (score 0):

There are too many smaller issues in the current code to try to debug them one-by-one, so this refactor introduces various tests against your data. It currently won't make any changes to your database and is meant to be a replacement for your `start()` function.

One of the main differences against your current code is that it doesn't unnecessarily download 4 collections worth of documents (two of them aren't even used in the code you've included).

### Steps

First, it will get all the bet documents that have `matched == false`. From these documents, it will check if they have any syntax errors and report them to the console. For each valid bet document, the ID of it's linked match document will be grabbed so we can then fetch all the match documents we actually need. Then we queue up the changes to the user's balance and the bet's document. Finally we report about any changes to be done and commit them (once you uncomment the line).

### Code

**Note:** `fetchDocumentById()` is [defined in this gist](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527). Its a helper function to allow `someCollectionRef.where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', arrayOfIds)` to take more than 10 IDs at once.

```js
async function applyBalanceChanges() {

  const betsCollectionRef = db.collection('bets');
  const matchesCollectionRef = db.collection('matches');
  const usersCollectionRef = db.collection('users');

  const betDataMap = {}; // Record<string, BetData>

  await betsCollectionRef
    .where('matched', '==', false)
    .get()
    .then((betsSnapshot) => {
      betsSnapshot.forEach(betDoc => {
        betDataMap[betDoc.id] = betDoc.data();
      });
    });
    
  const matchDataMap = {}; // Record<string, MatchData | undefined>
  
  // betIdList contains all IDs that will be processed
  const betIdList = Object.keys(betDataMap).filter(betId => {
    const betData = betDataMap[betId];
    
    if (!betData) {
      console.log(`WARN: Skipped Bet #${betId} because it was falsy (actual value: ${betData})`);
      return false;
    }
    
    const matchId = betData.tradeMatchId;
    if (!matchId) {
      console.log(`WARN: Skipped Bet #${betId} because it had a falsy match ID (actual value: ${matchId})`);
      return false;
    }
    
    if (!betData.user) {
      console.log(`WARN: Skipped Bet #${betId} because it had a falsy user ID (actual value: ${userId})`);
      return false;
    }
    
    const stakeAsNumber = Number(betData.stake); // not using parseFloat as it's too lax
    if (isNaN(stakeAsNumber)) {
      console.log(`WARN: Skipped Bet #${betId} because it had an invalid stake value (original NaN value: ${betData.stake})`);
      return false;
    }
    
    matchDataMap[matchId] = undefined; // using undefined because its the result of `doc.data()` when the document doesn't exist
    return true;
  });
  
  await fetchDocumentsById(
    matchesCollectionRef,
    Object.keys(matchIdMap),
    (matchDoc) => matchDataMap[matchDoc.id] = matchDoc.data()
  );
  
  const batch = db.batch();
  const queuedUpdates = 0;

  betIdList.forEach(betId => {
    const betData = betDataMap[betId];      
    const matchData = matchDataMap[betData.tradeMatchId];
    
    if (matchData === undefined) {
      console.log(`WARN: Skipped /bets/${betId}, because it's linked match doesn't exist!`);
      continue;
    }
    
    if (matchData.matchStatus !== 'IN_PLAY') {
      console.log(`INFO: Skipped /bets/${betId}, because it's linked match status is not "IN_PLAY" (actual value: ${matchData.matchStatus})`);
      continue;
    }
    
    const betRef = betsCollectionRef.doc(betId);
    const betUserRef = usersCollectionRef.doc(betData.user);
    
    batch.update(betUserRef, { accountBalance: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(Number(betData.stake)) });
    batch.update(betRef, { tradeCancelled: true });
    queuedUpdates += 2; // for logging
  });
  
  console.log(`INFO: Batch currently has ${queuedUpdates} queued`);

  // only uncomment when you are ready to make changes
  // batch.commit();
}
```

Usage:

```
axios.request(options)
  .then(function(response) {
    const data = response.data;

    console.log('INFO: Total matches count from API:' + data.matches.length);

    return applyBalanceChanges();
  }
```

Comment: thanks, let me try this, so you skip if the document value has a problem, but why does that happen to begin with?

Comment: @mac With proper security rules & validation, they shouldn't ever get skipped. I didn't have a screenshot of your database to work from, so I had to make a bunch of assumptions which I test against. While you could assume the data is correct, that could lead to dangerous bugs. Plus, by logging them, it should help find where your problem is if it ends up being a single document out of the hundreds in your database.